# Multiply multiple columns in a data frame with specific values from another data frame

Tags: r

Think about the following two data frames

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = rep(1, 10), b = rep(1, 10), c = rep(1, 10))
df2 <- data.frame(company = c("a", "b", "c"), weight = c(5, 10, 20))

df1

   a b c
1  1 1 1
2  1 1 1
3  1 1 1
4  1 1 1
5  1 1 1
6  1 1 1
7  1 1 1
8  1 1 1
9  1 1 1
10 1 1 1

df2

  company weight
1       a      5
2       b     10
3       c     20
```

I'm now looking for a solution that looks for the column names of df1 in the company column of df2 and multiplies each row of the corresponding company in df1 with the value from the weight column.

So what I want to achieve is:

```
df.weighted

   a.weighted b.weighted c.weighted
1           5         10         20
2           5         10         20
3           5         10         20
4           5         10         20
5           5         10         20
6           5         10         20
7           5         10         20
8           5         10         20
9           5         10         20
10          5         10         20
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could make the lengths of both the datasets same and multiply

```
out <- setNames(df2$weight, df2$company)[col(df1)] * df1
names(out) <- paste0(names(out), ".weighted")
```

---

Or another option is

```
df1 * split(df2$weight, df2$company)[names(df1)]
```

Or with `match`

```
df2$weight[match(names(df1), df2$company)][col(df1)] * df1
```

---

Or using `sweep`

```
sweep(df1[df2$company],  2, FUN = `*`, df2$weight)
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that data frames can be multiplied with vectors like this.I will use the match function, because this way not all columns in df1 have to match the entries in df2. Thanks again!

Comment: Just be careful about the different results of multiplying with `list`s vs `vectors` - `df1 * c(1,2,3)` vs `df1 * list(1,2,3)`

Comment: As thelatemail mentioned, here we are making the lengths same by replicating with `col`, otherwise, the recycling effect could change the output

Comment: I believe another option could be: `t(t(df1[df2$company]) * df2$weight)` The reason is to maintain the order of the companies, or even if fewer companies were selected from df1

Comment: I think the `match` version is safest as it both takes into account the ordering and can deal with non-matches as well by returning `NA`